# Are the senior Kree wearing make-up?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* season five, there are many Kree individuals. Most minor and background characters are "regular" all-blue Kree. However, the major Kree characters all have distinctive unique facial pigmentation - symmetrical light patches and black areas around the eyes. In particular Kasius, Sinara, Faulnak, and Taryan.

[image: Kasius and Sinara]

[image: Falunak][image: Taryan]

Out of universe, this serves to distinguish the named characters and make them easier to pick out and recognise. Is there any in-universe explanation anywhere? Are they wearing Kree make-up, have had some cosmetic procedure, or does their skin just look like that?

Kasius in particular is shown to be borderline obsessed with physical beauty. This could be partially a result of his own "imperfection", or alternatively could explain why he bothers with cosmetics to enhance himself.

The only other Kree I've spotted (across AoS and the MCU films up to *Avengers: Endgame*) who arguably wears cosmetics is Ronan in *Guardians of the Galaxy* - the black pigment is congealed Xandarian blood.

Comment: On a rewatch of *Guardians* I notice the Kree Emperor/Ambassador also has black lines on his face.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Yes, they are wearing makeup

We see this in Season 5 Episode 7, "Together or Not at All", of *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* where we actually see Kasius applying makeup to his face to cover up his new scar.

[image: Kasius applies makeup and the finished product]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

You can view the scene below.

This matches what we see of the Kree across the MCU as all Kree are either blue skinned, pink skinned (look like humans) or Korath. For example, look in the background of the train scene in Hala from *Captain Marvel* below where the blue skinned Kree are all "solid" blue skinned. The same goes for the named characters in *Captain Marvel* who all have solid blue skin.